# Merging distinct results SQL

Tags: python, sql, mariadb, union

So my problem is the following:
I have a MariaDB database that I am trying to query.
I am looking at experiment data. What I would like, is to summarize several experiments into one results row of an SQL query.

This is what the data looks like:

```
Experiment_ID | Antibiotic | Strain | Medium    | ...
1               Ampicillin   E. coli  TBauto      ...
2               Ampicillin   E. coli  TB + IPTG
```

What I would like to get:

```
Experiment_ID | Antibiotic | Strain | Medium               | ...
1               Ampicillin   E. coli  TBauto, TB + IPTG      ...
```

I don't care about the Experiment_ID, that is just there to make clear the I am talking about two distinct entries.

I already tried

```
Select
    tmp.*
From
    ((Select * from my_tbl Where ExperimentID = 1)
Union
    (Select * from my_tbl Where ExperimentID = 2)) as tmp
```

There I still end up with 2 rows of results. I could also do it in my `Python` code. But I would like to not have to modify results that I grab from the DB.

I guess I must have just been looking for the wrong word, to merge those two entries. So please kindly guide me in the right direction.

Comment: GROUP BY, group_concat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to want aggregation:

```
select min(Experiment_ID) as Experiment_ID, Antibiotic, Strain,
       group_concat(Medium order by Experiment_ID separator ', ')
from t
where Experiment_ID in (1, 2)
group by Antibiotic, Strain;
```

Comment: Does exactly what I wanted, thank you! I knew it was just the terminology that I had wrong... I was constantly looking for "grouping", "merging".